# Windows 7: how to redirect dhcp traffic to alternative port

Tags: windows, dhcp, port-forwarding, redirection, udp

I was hoping someone could help me find a way to force DHCP traffic to use an alternative port on Win7. I need windows to send and listen for dhcp traffic on a port other than 67/68.

I have tried to find a solution that involves port redirection (redirecting traffic on UDP 67/68 to another pair of ports), because to my knowledge it is not possible to change the listening ports of the Windows DHCP client. However, I have been unsuccessful thus far.

I look forward to you help.

Thanks,

~Arun

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this, keep in mind that you not only have to modify it on the Windows 7 client, but you'd also have to modify the it on the DHCP server as well.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: I am running Windows 7.

I need to run a private DHCP server within an enterprise network -- primarily for feature testing, and thus want to keep machines from using standard ports. I am modifying a Linux DHCP server to use non-standard ports as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your comments it would be best to just dynamic ranges but limit the server to known mac addresses. If you try to change ports like you are talking about PXE, BOOTP and other technologies won't work and as these are in firmwares and bios'es you would never have support. You would also need to apply any fixes you have before the system could get on the network so pushing the fix would be hard.

Look into mac reservations and just go that way, much better way to go.